# Web3 + Solidity: Passing in arguments to a contract's constructor

Tags: node.js, solidity, web3js

I am attempting to write some unit tests for a smart contract I'm writing, but am having difficulty when figuring out how to pass in arguments to my contract's constructor upon creation. Below is my code:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const provider = ganache.provider();
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
const { interface, bytecode } = require('../ethereum/compile');

let token;
let accounts;

beforeEach(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  token = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({ data: bytecode })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });
  token.setProvider(provider);
});

describe('Token Contract', () => { ... });
```

Based on this set up, how can I pass in arguments to the contract? I got this far by following a solidity course, but the contract in the lessons did not have any options for it's constructor, so it never covered where they should go. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright I figured it out on my own: add a property to the object you pass into the `deploy` function as an array of your arguments.

```
.deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: [ ... ] })
```